# How increase speed of counting CQL.toFilter("CONTAINS(the_geom, POINT (lat lon))") on GeoTools with Java

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools, point-in-polygon, cql-filter

How can I increase speed of counting?
I want to select points which is included by shape (GIS shapefile .shp).
I have 5 million points and 10 shape files.

```
    qry="CONTAINS(the_geom, POINT (69.95781 41.667324))";
    tName="WATER";
 
public Object[] filterFeatures(String qry,String tName) throws Exception {

    String[] typeNames=dataStore.getTypeNames();
    if(typeNames.length==0)return null;
    FeatureSource source =(FeatureSource) dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeNames[0]);
    Filter filter = CQL.toFilter(qry);
    FeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures(filter);
    Object[] objArr=features.toArray();
    return objArr;
 }
```

Comment: how many polygons are there in the shapefiles?

Comment: 183 polygons grouped into 5 shape files.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to answer this sort of question is to do some experimenting, so I tried out some quick and dirty tests using the Natural Earth populated places and admin countries - 7322 points and 177 polygons, and 3 test methods:

One that loops across the points doing a `contains` query (like you do):

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> pointLoop(SimpleFeatureCollection points, SimpleFeatureCollection polys,
      Expression propertyName) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = points.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature point = itr.next();
        Filter filter = filterFactory.contains(propertyName, filterFactory.literal(point.getDefaultGeometry()));
        SimpleFeatureCollection sub = polys.subCollection(filter);
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator fs = sub.features()) {
          while (fs.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature ff = fs.next();
            String name = (String) ff.getAttribute("NAME");
            if (results.containsKey(name)) {
              int count = results.get(name);
              results.put(name, count + 1);
            } else {
              results.put(name, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("PointLoop Time = " + (end - start) + "ms");
    return results;
  }
```

One that loops over the polygons and counts the points:

```
  public static HashMap<String, Integer> polygonLoop(SimpleFeatureCollection points, SimpleFeatureCollection polys,
      Expression propertyName) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = polys.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature poly = itr.next();
        Filter filter = filterFactory.within(propertyName, filterFactory.literal(poly.getDefaultGeometry()));
        SimpleFeatureCollection sub = points.subCollection(filter);
        results.put((String) poly.getAttribute("NAME"), sub.size());

      }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Polygon Loop Time = " + (end - start) + "ms");
    return results;
  }
```

and finally one that uses a `SpatialIndexFeatureCollection` on the points to improve the speed of the point in polygon query:

```
  public static HashMap<String, Integer> polygonLoopIndex(SimpleFeatureCollection points, SimpleFeatureCollection polys,
      Expression propertyName) throws IOException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>();
    SpatialIndexFeatureCollection index = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection(points);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = polys.features()) {
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature poly = itr.next();
        Filter filter = filterFactory.within(propertyName, filterFactory.literal(poly.getDefaultGeometry()));
        SimpleFeatureCollection sub = index.subCollection(filter);
        results.put((String) poly.getAttribute("NAME"), sub.size());

      }
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Indexed Polygon Loop Time = " + (end - start) + "ms");
    return results;
  }
```

I got the following results:

```
Point Loop Time = 3566ms
Polygon Loop Time = 151ms
Indexed Polygon Loop Time = 186ms
```

so the polygon by polygon loop wins. But I then turned up the size of the points collection and this is the result:

```
500,000 points
177 polygons
Point Loop Time = 146.029s
Polygon Loop Time = 12.517s
Indexed Polygon Loop Time = 2.801s
```

So beyond a certain point building the index pays off and it is worth the effort.

Comment: It is very good solution! But I use geotools 2.6 version. I cant get newer version of geotools. Which geotools version are you u sing?

Comment: I am using 26.x master version - to use a version 20 versions old is probably a mistake

Comment: Sorry can you tell me what is the value of propertyName?

Comment: What ever your geometry is

Comment: `polygonLoopIndex(getPOINTS(),getPolygons("8"), CQL.toExpression("???")); `  What do I have to write instead of question mark?

Comment: private static SimpleFeatureType createPOINTType() {

        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("Location");
        builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS8

Comment: private static SimpleFeatureType createPolygonType() {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("MyPolygon");
        builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

Comment: CQL.toExpression("Location.* containing  MyPolygon.*") is it right?

Comment: Expression propertyName = filterFactory.property(points.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getName());

Comment: which FilterFactory do I have to use?

Comment: Either `FilterFactory` or `FilterFactory2` will be fine

Comment: I used FilterFactory2 filterFactory = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(); but result.size=1 and value of 0 th indice is 0. Not selecting points!

Comment: see https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2138385 for my full code example

Comment: Thank you for your honestly helping!

Answer (score -1):

```
CQL.toExpression("the_geom,location.*") is correct!
```

Comment: Not worked Sorry